# vb.net read file line by line and copy some part of the Line

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, streamreader, readline

I have this code to read the read the lines of a file (16file) and then show each line in a textbox (tWLine), one at a time but the code below shows all the contents of the file at once. However I want it such that after a line of the file is read, it is shown in the textbox (tWline) and then a button is clicked before the next line is read and shown in the textbox again till the last line in the 16file.

The second part will be to copy the words in the line that is read into textboxes based on the number  of the word in the line (1st word into txt1, 2nd into txt2, etc) but I will be most grateful to at least get through with even the first part alone.

```
    `Dim fRdr As StreamReader

    fRdr = File.OpenText("C:\users\sk\16file.txt")

    'Loop through to read Lines
    Do Until fRdr.EndOfStream
        tWLine.Text = tWLine.Text & fRdr.ReadLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    fRdr.Close()`
```

I would like the textbox contents to appear like the code below shows the messages one line at a time so that after each line has shown in the tWline textbox, some form of code will be performed before the next line is read and then the same thing will be done for the next line till the last line in the file is reached.

```
    `Private Sub bReadFA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bReadFA.Click
    For Each Line As String In File.ReadLines("C:\users\sk\16file.txt")
        MsgBox(line)
    Next
End Sub `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean transfer each line of your file in textbox? try this

change `Msgbox(line)` to `YourTextbox.Text = line`

Try this one

```
Private Sub bReadFA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bReadFA.Click
For Each Line As String In File.ReadLines("C:\users\sk\16file.txt")
YourTextbox.Text = line
await Task.Delay(1000)//Await a second
Next
```

Comment: That one only shows the last line of the file in the textbox. thank you for the help, anyway.

Comment: do you figured out the answer?

Comment: Nope. Same olf story.

Comment: try the updated answer if this one works please accept

Comment: Thank you, @Shadow fiend. Great help. After every second, the next line of the file is brought in the textbox. I will now increase the delay time.

Comment: Actually all of the lines in your text file has been displayed one by one but in a fastest way that even a naked eye cant see hahah. so for you to make visible you can set a delay. Actually I didnt know that theres a delay in a loop. 1st time in 3 yrs of programming hahaha

Comment: Hello,  @Shadow fiend,  I am trying to use this same block of code in a new Project I am developing but the VS tells me  await can only be used with the Async method. When I edit the `private sub ` to `Private Async Sub and await is okay but it gives the error message "Task is not declared". Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

If Shadow Fiend's answer doesn't worked for you then you might not having multiple lines in your text file. If you mean sentence by saying line, then you better copy all the text in the file to a String variable and split it by means of '.' to get the string array. and then simply do what ever you want the the array.

Comment: Very true, @aaditua dengle. The file has multiple lines and it worked as expected.

Comment: He's true atleast you can take this answer as a guide also if the text inside the textfile has no `newline` you can split them by **`.`**

Comment: @aadita dengle Can you help me with this as well, I want to copy the words in a line into textboxes based on the position of the word in the sentence (line). That is the first word in the sentence goes to textbox1, second word goes to textbox2, up to the 10 word in the sentence.

Comment: @MordC After splitting the whole file text with dot (.) you will get the array. Then you will just need to access the individual array member and split that too with Space(" "), You will get another array. Which you can link with the Array of your textboxs